# Issue reading the content of a DatasnapShot obtained from the ChildEventListener() for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to extract the field values from the dataSnapshot.

Here is the code:

```
ChildEventListener userListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG,"users count:"+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()+" users");

        for(DataSnapshot receivedSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"received Snapshot"+receivedSnapshot);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"received Snapshot"+receivedSnapshot,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Person person  = receivedSnapshot.getValue(Person.class)// Getting the error for this line.

            Log.i(TAG,"receivedSnapshot:"+person.toString());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

dataBase =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference userTable = dataBase.getReference("users");
userTable.addChildEventListener(userListener);
```

Here is the logcat:

```
Process: com.example.raghavkishan.wealthmanagement, PID: 23843
Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:website.leifs.delta, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.raghavkishan.wealthmanagement.Person
```

My Person Class:

```
private String personName;
private String personEmail;
private int phoneNumber;
private String dateOfBirth;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String groupId;

public Person(String personName,String personEmail,int phoneNumber,String dateOfBirth,String city,String state,String country,String groupId){
    this.personName = personName;
    this.personEmail = personEmail;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.country = country;
    this.groupId = groupId;

}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

The image contains the database structure. The UID of the user is the key to the node.

[image]

I am using an object of the Person class to post the data to the firebase database. But while retrieving it I am encountering the above error.

1)What mistake am I making?

2)Any alternative method?

Comment: Please post the Person class definition and firebase node

Comment: Please add you database structure and your pojo.

Comment: @SushobhNadiger I have updated the post with the person class and database structure

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated the post with the person class and database structure

Answer (score 1):

Your `DatabaseReference` is wrong. You need to change this line:

```
DatabaseReference userTable = dataBase.getReference("users");
```

with

```
DatabaseReference userTable = dataBase.getReference("users").child(userId);
```

The problem is that you are missing a child, the `userId` child. `userId` is the unique id that is generated by the `push()` method.

Hope it helps.